# Content of TinyMCE invisible but present

Tags: tinymce

I use tinymce in a modal-window showing some db-content.
This works only the first time the window is dislplayed until I hide the window.

The second time the window is shown tinymce did not show up. So I had a few trys with reload or destroy until I came up with this:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.editors = [];

tinymce.init({
selector: '#input-inhalt',
height :300,
skin: "custom",......
```

Now it works... the editor is shown as expected but the content is invisible. I can inspect the html-code with the toolbutton or check the object in console-log. The text is there but the editor remains blank. I even checked the color white...
Any hints what I could check or a workaround?

Here a full codeexample what I try to do:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js'></script>

<script>
var z = 0;
function close1() {
    $('#content').hide();
}

function setup() {
    z += 1;
    mytext = 'my individual text to be loaded:' + z;
    $('#mytext').val(mytext);
    tinymce.EditorManager.editors = [];
    $('#content').show();       
    alert(z);

    tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytext',

    height :300,
    skin: "custom",
    plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste imagetools  textcolor colorpicker "
        ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | forecolor backcolor emoticons | fontselect |  fontsizeselect",
    language : "de",
    entity_encoding : "raw",  //umlaute  nicht in &uuml;... wandeln (textarea)
    relative_urls: false,
    themes: "modern", 

     });
 }

</script>

<div id="frame">
    <div id="content">
        <p> </p>
        <input type="textarea" id = "mytext"/>
    </div>      
    <input type="button" value="open" onclick="javascript:setup();">
    <input type="button" value="close" onclick="javascript:close1();">
</div>
```

Note: the first show is correct, but in the second show the value of z does not increase.

Comment: Without seeing running code I don't know that anyone can tell you what's happening here. Please see How do I ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks Michael. I enclosed an example and could see Im on the wrong track... but still have an empty frame